# Who can help us complete an English translation of Yoreh Deah?

Tags: discussion

Did you know there is still no English translation of Yoreh Deah, in particular available online, even today (June 2020)?  Are you willing to volunteer a little of your learning time to help complete a translation already underway but needing more hands?

Then please go to http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Yoreh_Deah
and start editing.  A username and account, easily created, are helpful but not required.

If it's in your "Portion in [His] Torah" to help in this imminently good and essential project then B"H you will help and count yourself in.  My wish is to just promote this translation and learning aid to be completed quickly; and my other efforts have fallen on deaf or preoccupied ears.

This is better than -- or is an excellent addition to -- the usual learning with a chavruta, insofar as your learning will last forever, retained and uncorrupted, as edits on Wikisource (sister of Wikipedia) are CC Creative Commons copyleft and have a permanent digital footprint on a wide and well established platform that is easy to use.  Though others may come and b"h improve your edits, the history of all edits can be viewed on the "View History" tab.

Comment: Great initiative. I hope you're in touch with Sefaria to make sure they leverage your work. Will be a great "distribution channel" for the content your community creates

Comment: @Mordechai_Schmerler Awesome -- As of a Mar 2020 communication with the Sefaria Mgr. of Text Acquisition, I was told there aren't automatic exchanges in place with Wikisource, however if someone informs them of complete Simanim at Wikisource they can get their engineers to upload them to Sefaria.  Several engineers are listed at https://www.sefaria.org/team  Chazaq

Comment: I would appreciate a similar initiative for Orach Chayim. Unfortunately my Hebrew is not good enough, but I still see serious mistakes, and a good general editing would be also necessary. [I started to correct a few errors, but I'm not enough alone.]

Comment: @Kazi_bácsi Done! https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/shulchan-arukh-orach-chayim-status-of-online-english-translations-stat

Comment: @MordechaiSchmerler How's it going? Did you upload those simanim, or do you need any help with the wiki markup?