# Shulchan Arukh (Orach Chayim, ...) -- status of online English translations status -- let's consolidate at Wikisource and aim to complete it?

Tags: discussion

I posted [Who can help us complete an English translation of Yoreh Deah?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/) but it's been pointed out SAOC has the same status, so let this be a planning board for the other sections of SA.  Whoever can, please edit this and update periodically.

---

ORACH CHAYIM

There is still no complete SAOC English translation online as of August 2020.

For Orach Chayim, here is what I've found:

1. At Sefaria several English translations are listed (though hard to navigate to tell what version has what Simanim; also the TOC shows a straight numeric 1-697 without Topic groupings). The "Sefaria Community (en)" translation comprises the vast majority available.  On 8/13/2020 I navigated to

   https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim?lang=bi > Download > Sefaria Community Translation > Text file

   and retrieved 1,025,074 bytes.  Doing the same for Merged Version (en) fetched 1,113,455 bytes.  The Sefaria Community translation is CC0 which is Public Domain.
2. At https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim the Simanim are arranged by topic, and most simanim have a title already.  The copyleft CC-BY-SA is standard there.
3. SAOC at http://www.shulchanarach.com/ by Dr. Jay Dinovitser D.O. was 15% complete but he's very occupied as of Aug. 2020.  No license is stated.

---

SAEH

?

---

SACM

?

---

---

Solutions:

- Perhaps someone has a complete work offline and will have the zechut to publish it online.
- Meanwhile let's import the Sefaria community version into Wikisource and go from there.  I like the Wikisource platform because it's easy to use, easy to format, transparent, and you can edit it from any web connection -- even without an account, though I think editing under an account will be better.  There is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser tool that might help import the txt file from Sefaria.

Comment: As I saw, Sefaria took the available parts from WS, and then continued to translate a few parts on their own site. But again, the quality of translation is very random.

Comment: @Kazi_bácsi Wikisource has a {{Textquality|100}}, {{Textquality|75}}, 50, 25 tag https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Wikisource:Text_quality  
For example 50% means it's Complete and Formatted but may contain errors.  This appears as a colored icon on the "Page" tab for example 50% is two purple squares out of four.

Comment: And are you sure that you can bulk download materials from Sefaria? Aren't they copyrighted?

Comment: @Kazi_bácsi SefariaCommunity Translation is CC0 (=PD), like it says under the Version list.  Publisher translations are supposed to state the license but many do not.  For example, I asked about the Asher Meza in YD and the admin said it was uploaded by a user, and is available at the author's website, without further license details, so license is unknown.